# Color Resource with type #0x1d is not valid for android:colorAccent

Tags: android, android-resources, android-theme, android-5.0-lollipop

I have the following error when starting an `Activity` on `Android 5` (on a `Nexus 5`).

```
10-23 10:39:43.218    6823-6823/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: eu.elios.gpstracker.app, PID: 6823
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eu.elios.gpstracker.app/eu.elios.gpstracker.app.MessageListActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070045 type #0x1d is not valid
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070045 type #0x1d is not valid
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2603)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:1098)
        at android.transition.TransitionInflater.inflateTransition(TransitionInflater.java:75)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getTransition(PhoneWindow.java:3696)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3649)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:367)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
        at eu.elios.gpstracker.app.MessageListActivity.onCreate(MessageListActivity.java:81)
```

By looking at the `Resource ID` on R I found that the resource is the color I use for my `android:colorAccent` in:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/controlHighlight</item>

    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">?android:colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">?android:colorPrimaryDark</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
</style>
```

The `Resource` itself is:

```
<color name="accent">@color/md_deep_orange_500</color>
<color name="md_deep_orange_500">#ff5722</color>
```

By changing the `Color` to some other colors (like `@color/primaryDark`) I get the same error but with the `ID` of the new color.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try explicitly adding the alpha value i.e.

```
<color name="md_deep_orange_500">#ffff5722</color>
```

Comment: This worked. Is it needed only for the accent color?

Comment: To fix this problem, I've updated the Gist to get these colors: [Material Design Color Resources](https://gist.github.com/dadino/fe94621c5b4162f737b9)

Comment: I think it is related to the "double link". I suppose double linking a color works only if alpha is explicitly declared

Comment: The error doesn't indicate anything about loading a color -- it was trying to pass @color/accent to TransitionInflater.inflateTransition(), which shouldn't happen unless your resource table is broken or something is wrong in your XML. Running a clean build would probably fix the former. Can you still reproduce the issue if you change it back to an RGB color?